# Failure to download extra data files, ttf

Tags: downloads

Sometimes I am receving this window with message:
[image]

When i press "run this action now" It asks me to authenticate, but I cant.
[image]

Comment: Are you in the admin (a.k.a. sudo) group on this system? Only admins can make system wide changes!

Comment: I guess yes, I always use sudo to install smth, etc